# Replacing unicode in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

here is the result I print out by python:

> `With \u003cb\u003eall\u003c/b\u003e respect, if we look from one
>   perspective, it is just like looking at ants.`

and the data type is

> `<type 'unicode'>`

Is there gonna be a way to replace **`\u003cb\u003e` by `''`**? I have tried

> `str.replace("\u003cb\u003e", '')`, `str.replace("\\u003cb\\u003e",
>   '')` and `str.replace("<b>", '')` but none of them worked

. How can properly replace it by an empty string?

edited:

here is the result of `print repr(mystrung)`:

```
With \\u003cb\\u003eall\\u003c/b\\u003e respect, if we look from one
perspective, it is just like looking at ants.
```

Comment: It's unclear what's part of the string itself and what's just part of its representation.  What does `print(repr(your_string))` show?

Comment: It looks like your unicode string has been badly constructed. This: `u'With \u003cb\u003eall\u003c/b\u003e respect'` is just the same as `u'With <b>all</b> respect'` because `u'\u003c'` **is** `u'\x3c'` and actually is `'<'`.  You should try to fix it upstream...

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to remove them completely, your second example should have worked.  Using Unicode strings is more efficient, though, since an implicit conversion is eliminated:

```
>>> s=u'With \\u003cb\\u003eall\\u003c/b\\u003e respect, if we look from one perspective, it is just like looking at ants.'
>>> s.replace(u'\\u003cb\\u003e',u'').replace(u'\\u003c/b\\u003e',u'')
u'With all respect, if we look from one perspective, it is just like looking at ants.'
```

If you'd rather just convert the Unicode escapes, encoding a Unicode string containing only ASCII codepoints with `ascii` converts it back to a byte string, then decode it with `unicode-escape` to turn the literal escape codes back to characters:

```
>>> print(s.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))
With <b>all</b> respect, if we look from one perspective, it is just like looking at ants.
```